# How can I obtain the count of running threads for a process using Performance Counters?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

Given the below code, I can get the total number of active threads for a given process:

```
using (var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Threads.Count);     
}
```

I would like to achieve this using `PerformanceCounters` and have so far tried (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8f5kw2e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var category = ".NET CLR LocksAndThreads";
var counterOne = "# of current logical Threads";
var counterTwo = "# of current physical Threads";
var coutnerThree = "# of current recognized threads";
var counterFour = "# of total recognized Threads";

var perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
    category,
    counterOne,
    "myProcess") { ReadOnly = true };
Console.WriteLine("Thread count: ", perfCounter.NextValue());
```

I have been unable to match the number returned by the `Process`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Process.Threads` is going to include all threads, including native OS threads. The .NET performance counter is only going to return managed threads. The performance counter that'd match `Process.Threads` would be `\\Process(myProcess)\Thread Count`